# 3D Rotation warps cube

Tags: java, 3d, rotation, java-3d

I've been creating a 3D engine over the past few weeks, and I've managed to get translation and scaling for my objects. But I'm having a slight issue with my rotations.
When I try rotating my cube 45 degrees on the z-axis, it becomes warped.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bozW1.png)

Here is where all my calculations for the cubes rotation are. 'vertices' is an array containing all points in my cube. The code is limited to just rotating along the z-axis.

```
    public void rotate(vec3 r) {
    rotation.add(r);

    float sinZ = (float) Math.sin(Math.toRadians(r.z));
    float cosZ = (float) Math.cos(Math.toRadians(r.z));

    for (int vdx = 0; vdx < vertices.size(); vdx++) {
        vec3 v = vertices.get(vdx);

        v.x = v.x * cosZ - v.y * sinZ;

        v.y = v.y * cosZ + v.x * sinZ;

        vertices.set(vdx, v);
    }
}
```

Assume the cube is at the location (0, 0, 0)

I would preferably like to do this without using external modules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need temporary variables x, y like:

```
    x = v.x * cosZ - v.y * sinZ;
    y = v.y * cosZ + v.x * sinZ;

    v.x = x;
    v.y = y;
```

Otherwise the computation of v.y is using the wrong v.x